# Apache, MySQL & PHP on macOS Big Sur. PHP not working

Tags: php, apache

I am trying to Apache, MySQL & PHP on macOS Big Sur.

I have followed this guide:
https://tobschall.de/2020/11/01/big-sur-mamp/

And have configured my
`/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`
as

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot "/Users/myname/Sites/test"
  ServerName local.idex
</VirtualHost>
```

and my
`/etc/hosts`

```
127.0.0.1       localhost local.test
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
```

if I put the following php file (`phpinfo.php`)

```
echo '<?php phpinfo();' > /Library/WebServer/Documents/phpinfo.php
```

in the test directory and type http://localhost/phpinfo.php in a browser, I get

echo '<?php phpinfo();' > /Library/WebServer/Documents/phpinfo.php

which is basically what I put on the file.

Looks like the php is not working :-(

I have checked:

1. that Apache is running (http://localhost gives 'It Works')
   and
2. that forcing php (php -S localhost:8080) does not help.

Any idea ?

Comment: `sudo a2enmod phpX` where X is the version maybe?

Comment: Thanks but a2enmod is not recognized on Mac

Comment: Your asking the question on the wrong website, this question could easily be answered on https://serverfault.com

Answer (score 1):

For those with the same problem.
I found the solution here (https://wpbeaches.com/install-apache-mysql-php-on-macos-11-big-sur-and-earlier-macos/)
Just add

```
LoadModule php7_module libexec/apache2/libphp7.so
```

in your /etc/apache2/httpd.conf file.